Invalid "default" export for Page Component in App Router
I'm getting a TypeScript error in my Next.js 13 App Router project when trying to deploy my project to Vercel. This is the error I am getting - there is no other error message.
Failed to compile.
Type error: Page "src/app/dashboard/knowledge-vault/page.tsx" has an invalid "default" export:
  Type "KnowledgeVaultPageProps" is not valid.

Current Code:
type KnowledgeVaultPageProps = {
    hasAssistant: boolean;
    userEmail: string;
    dashboardData: {
        assistant?: AssistantMetadata;
    };
}

export default function KnowledgeVaultPage(props: KnowledgeVaultPageProps) {
    // Component implementation
}

How do I properly type this page component in Next.js 13 App Router? The documentation for Pages Router typing (https://nextjs.org/docs/app/api-reference/file-conventions/page) doesn't seem to apply here, and I need to maintain my existing props while conforming to the App Router's page requirements.
Environment:

Next.js 13 (App Router)
TypeScript
use client directive is being used

Any help would be appreciated!
